# LaTeX editor similar to Word

Tags: editors

My supervisor asked me to give him a Word version of the paper to edit and comment. I used free [latex2rtf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/latex2rtf/?source=dlp) to convert my document to word. I cannot say that it's perfect, but it saved my time. I was wondering if there is a LaTeX editor with one of this features:

LaTeX editor similar to Word environment which hides all the `\begin{}` `\end{}` commands. Therefore, a non-LaTeX person can edit the document.

Comment: have you seen [My phd supervisor wants me to use Word because they can't edit LaTeX. What to do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70050)

Comment: that's great, in which case I'll flag this for a moderator to look at- they may choose to close it as a duplicate just to keep the site tidy :)

Comment: totally agreed.

Comment: For those interested in LaTeX *without* the code bits, many migrate to using [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/). However, you need a proper understanding of LyX templates to create anything custom-made. Otherwise, sticking to the ordinary/default setup should provide them with something Word-ish to look at...