# Add a paragraph sign for each paragraph

Tags: paragraphs, msword

Because my supervisor don't like review my papers with PDF format, I have to find a solution to convert my `.tex` files to `.doc` file. However, the solutions given in many forums beyond my level. So I use the following way to deal with my problem.

1. Generating PDF use LaTeX;
2. Use solid PDF converter to convert PDF to Word.

But the generated word file have many problems, such as

1. Some line-ending words are separated by hyphen `-`:
   (for this, I use `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` to solve it);
2. The paragraphs are split to several paragraph by accident.
   for this, I want to generate a paragraph sign in PDF file by latex.
   such as, after each paragraph, add a paragraph sign (say `_ppp_`) in PDF by LaTeX formatting. With this paragraph sign, I could easily replace `_ppp_` to normal paragraph in Office Word. The question is how?**

**And, I also want to format the section and/or subsection by adding a sign (say `_h1_` or `_h2_`)**

---

I just want how to add something at the end of papagraph. Just like this,

## Section 1_h1_

### Subsection 1_h2_

paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content._ppp_

paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content._ppp_

## Section 1_h1_

### Subsection 2_h2_

paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content, paragraph content._ppp_

Comment: This simply won't end well.  See [My PhD supervisor wants me to use Word because they can't edit LaTeX. What to do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70050/)

Comment: The pilcrow (¶) is a typographical mark that’s universally accepted to mean a new paragraph. (These are called **Formatting marks** in Microsoft Word.) This old TeX.sx question might help you somewhat with (1): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41711/how-to-join-paragraphs-with-a-pilcrow-p

Comment: Thanks very much, but I had difficulty to build my latex file using the pilcrow. So I still just want to know how to add something at the end of each paragraph.

Comment: It would be better to use something like `tex4ht` to periodically convert the file rather than add a bunch of arbitrary signs to help solve the confusing output that results from so 'static' a conversion.  You can simplify the conversion process by using a conditional to get rid of fancy formatting when you want to convert -- somethinig like `\newif\ifmsword` then `\ifmsword <simplified output> \else <normal output>`.  Then, just add a `\mswordtrue` when you are going to use `tex4ht` (which also can be helpful on its own!).

Comment: Thank you very much to give the idea of getting rid of fancy formatting.
However, I am new to this latex world, how to setup that newif staff? in beamer?

\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifmsword


\begin{document}
\ifmsword 
<simplified output> 
\else
 <normal output>
\fi
blabla

\end{document}

Comment: It would be easier to suggest how to simplify if you edit your answer to show the preamble of your `.tex` file (a complete minimal example would be even better).

Comment: Hints on [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) as @jon suggested

Answer (score 3):

If you know any VBA you can walk the text file and when you find `\section{...}` put the contents of the `{}` in a different style (or just bigger+bold) and append the `_h1_`.  I'm doing this for a paper I'm working on at the moment.

The code below is pasted from my normal.dot for word 2003, with some personal stuff removed.  You'll need to add *Microsoft regular expressions* to your VBA project's references.  No attempt is made to handle significant math or tables, but pictures are loaded if they exist as .png.  I found for body text, captions etc., with the goal of collaborative editing, this worked better than going via pandoc or any of the other converters I tried.  I just keep adding to it as I add new commands to my .tex source (hence the partial implementation of `acronym`, which is already out of date).

`Option Explicit
Option Base 0`

Sub ImportTexFile()

If Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen).Show <> -1 Then End

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=Left(ActiveDocument.FullName, Len(ActiveDocument.FullName) - 4) & "-import.doc", FileFormat _
    :=wdFormatDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:= _
    False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False

End Sub

'ReadTeX reads in a .TeX file and tries to interpret it.
' make sure graphics are available in .png, e.g. use imagemagick:
'FOR %a in (*.pdf) DO convert -density 300 "%~a"  "%~na.png"

Sub ReadTeX()
Dim strFName As String
Dim oReg As New RegExp
Dim strLineArr() As String
Dim strText As String
Dim strtemp As String
Dim iLine As Integer
Dim bInBody As Boolean
Dim bTempBody As Boolean
Dim strArg As String, strCom As String
Dim bInMath As Boolean
Dim iPic As Integer
Dim bKillComment As Boolean 'delete comments? alternative is to grey out
Dim UcodeBase As Integer
Dim strAcro() As String

bKillComment = True
'strText = ActiveDocument.Range.Text
ImportTexFile
strFName = ActiveDocument.FullName
strLineArr = Split(ActiveDocument.Content.Text, Chr(13))

setOptions
ReDim strAcro(2, 1) As String
'throw away all preamble and anything after \end(document)
bInBody = False
For iLine = 0 To UBound(strLineArr)
bTempBody = bInBody
If Left(strLineArr(iLine), 16) = "\begin{document}" Then bTempBody = True
If Left(strLineArr(iLine), 14) = "\end{document}" Then
  bTempBody = False
  bInBody = False
End If
If Not bInBody Then
  If Left(Trim(strLineArr(iLine)), 8) = "\newacro" Then
    strtemp = Trim(strLineArr(iLine))
    strtemp = Right(strtemp, Len(strtemp) - 8)
    ReDim Preserve strAcro(2, UBound(strAcro, 2) + 1) As String
    strAcro(0, UBound(strAcro, 2)) = Mid(strtemp, 2, InStr(strtemp, "}") - 2)
    strAcro(1, UBound(strAcro, 2)) = _
    Mid(strtemp, 4 + Len(strAcro(0, UBound(strAcro, 2))), InStr(4 + Len(strAcro(0, UBound(strAcro, 2))), strtemp, "}") - 4 - Len(strAcro(0, UBound(strAcro, 2))))
    strAcro(2, UBound(strAcro, 2)) = "False" ' has this acronym been spelt out yet
  End If
  strLineArr(iLine) = ""
End If
bInBody = bTempBody
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveDocument.Range.Text = ""
For iLine = 0 To UBound(strLineArr)
  If Len(strLineArr(iLine)) > 0 Then ActiveDocument.Range.Text = ActiveDocument.Range.Text & strLineArr(iLine)
Next
Application.ScreenRefresh

'display after removal of preamble etc.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'line-by-line cleanup of some common commands and some of my stuff - anything that doesn't need formatting
strLineArr = Split(ActiveDocument.Content.Text, Chr(13))
For iLine = 0 To UBound(strLineArr)
  strText = strLineArr(iLine)

'\slash
  oReg.Global = True
  oReg.Multiline = False
  oReg.Pattern = "\slash({}|\s)?"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, "/")

'\hyp (hyphen)
  oReg.Pattern = "\hyp(({})|\s)?"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, "-")

'~ (nbsp)'regex is overkill here, but never mind
  oReg.Pattern = "~"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, Chr(160))

'--- (emdash)'regex is overkill here, but never mind
  oReg.Pattern = "---"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, ChrW(&H2014))

'-- (endash)'regex is overkill here, but never mind
  oReg.Pattern = "--"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, ChrW(&H2013))

'\cite, \citeauthor (slightly cleverer) - square brackets around citation key
  oReg.Pattern = "\cite(author|numns)?{([\w, \?-_[]]*)}"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, "[$2]")
   ' (slightly cleverer) - square brackets around citation key

'\author, email, affiliation - just return bare
  oReg.Pattern = "\(author|email|affiliation){([\w.,@ \?]*)}"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, "$2")

'\maketitle - just remove
  oReg.Pattern = "\maketitle"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, "")

'comments starting with % - running to end of line - but only if % isn't preceded by \
  oReg.Pattern = "([^\]%|^%).*$"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, "")

'remove figure placement commands
  oReg.Pattern = "[[htbp!H]+]"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, "")

'my stuff

'\um{} to give micron
  oReg.Global = True
  oReg.Multiline = False
  oReg.Pattern = "\um({})?"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, Chr(181) & "m")

'\textdeg{} to give degree
  oReg.Global = True
  oReg.Multiline = False
  oReg.Pattern = "\textdeg({})?"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, "°")

'\textasciitilde{} to give tilde
  oReg.Global = True
  oReg.Multiline = False
  oReg.Pattern = "\textasciitilde({})?"
  strText = oReg.Replace(strText, "~")

strLineArr(iLine) = strText
Next
ActiveDocument.Range.Text = ""
For iLine = 0 To UBound(strLineArr)
  If Len(strLineArr(iLine)) > 0 Then ActiveDocument.Range.Text = ActiveDocument.Range.Text & strLineArr(iLine)
Next
Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory, Extend:=True
Selection.Style = "Normal"
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify

'now it's easiest to walk the document to allow formatting
bInMath = False
Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
Do Until ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Sel").End = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").End
Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=True

If Selection.Text = "\" Then 'here's where it gets interesting
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=True
  If InStr("#$%&^_{}~", Right(Selection.Text, 1)) Then 'first deal with simple escaped characters
    Selection.Text = Right(Selection.Text, 1)
  ElseIf Selection.Text = "\" Then Selection.Text = Chr(13) 'and forced line breaks
  Else
    Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=True
    strCom = Trim(Selection.Text)
   ' If strCom = "\Wmk" Then Stop
    Selection.Delete
    strArg = CaptureBraces
    Select Case strCom
    Case "\comment": 'block comments in the code - either delete or grey-out
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg), Extend:=True
      If bKillComment Then
        Selection.Delete
      Else
        Selection.Font.Color = wdColorGray40
        Selection.Font.Size = Selection.Font.Size - 2
        Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
      End If
      Selection.Delete
    Case "\warn": 'make a word comment from a note to self
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=True
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) + 1, Extend:=True
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
      Selection.TypeText Text:=strArg
      Selection.EscapeKey
      If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Index > 1 Then ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Close
      'not yet working through the argument of this one
    Case "\section":
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg), Extend:=True
      Selection.Font.Bold = True
      Selection.Font.Size = Selection.Font.Size + 4
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) 'need to work through the argument
    Case "\subsection":
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg), Extend:=True
      Selection.Font.Bold = True
      Selection.Font.Size = Selection.Font.Size + 2
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) 'need to work through the argument
    Case "\ref": 'do nothing for now - leave as ref for cross referencing later
    Case "\emph":
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=True
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg), Extend:=True
      Selection.Font.Italic = True
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) + 1 'need to work through the argument
    Case "\title":
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=True
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg), Extend:=True
      Selection.Font.Bold = True
      Selection.Font.Size = Selection.Font.Size + 8
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
      Selection.Delete
      Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg)

```
Case "\caption":
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=True
  Selection.Delete
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg), Extend:=True
  Selection.Font.Size = Selection.Font.Size - 2
  Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
  Selection.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = Selection.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent + InchesToPoints(0.5)
  Selection.ParagraphFormat.RightIndent = Selection.ParagraphFormat.RightIndent + InchesToPoints(0.5)
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  Selection.Delete
  Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) + 1 'need to work through the caption
Case "\label": 'do nothing - keep the label in braces

Case "\begin":
  Select Case strArg
    Case "abstract", "figure":
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) + 2, Extend:=True
      Selection.Delete
  End Select
Case "\end":
  Select Case strArg
    Case "abstract", "figure":
      Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) + 2, Extend:=True
      Selection.Delete
  End Select
Case "\si" 'siunitx package - try to interpret units, or just leave as text
  Selection.Delete
  'Selection.Delete
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg)
  Selection.Delete
  Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg)
Case "\textsuperscript":
  doSuper (strArg)
Case "\textsubscript":
  doSub (strArg)
Case "\bibliographystyle", "\bibliography": 'stuf to just wipe out
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) + 2, Extend:=2
  Selection.Delete
Case "\includegraphics":
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) + 2, Extend:=True
  Selection.Delete
  Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Trim(strArg) & ".png", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
  iPic = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
  'ipic =Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Trim(strArg) & ".png", False, True)
  With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(iPic - 1)
    .Height = InchesToPoints(3.5) * .Height / .Width
    .Width = InchesToPoints(3.5)
  End With
'Math mode stuff - can test bInMath (see below)
Case "\leq":
  Selection.InsertBefore (ChrW(8804))
Case "\times":
  Selection.InsertBefore (ChrW(215))
'greek letters
Case "\alpha", "\Alpha", "\beta", "\Beta", "\gamma", "\Gamma", "\delta", "\Delta", "\epsilon", "\Epsilon", "\zeta", "\Zeta", "\eta", "\Eta", "\theta", "\Theta", "\iota", "\Iota", "\kappa", "\Kappa", "\lambda", "\Lambda", "\mu", "\Mu", "\nu", "\Nu", "\xi", "\Xi", "\omicron", "\Omicron", "\pi", "\Pi", "\rho", "\Rho", "\sigma", "\Sigma", "\tau", "\Tau", "\upsilon", "\Upsilon", "\phi", "\Phi", "\chi", "\Chi", "\psi", "\Psi", "\omega", "\Omega":
  If LCase(Mid(strCom, 2, 1)) = Mid(strCom, 2, 1) Then 'lower case
    UcodeBase = 945
  Else 'upper case
    UcodeBase = 913
  End If
  strCom = LCase(strCom)
  Selection.InsertAfter ChrW(UcodeBase + FindGreek(Right(Trim(strCom), Len(Trim(strCom)) - 1)))

Case "\acl", "\acp", "\acf", "\acfp", "\ac", "\acp", "\acs", "\acsp", "\aclp":
'acronyms
Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) + 2, Extend:=True
Selection.Delete
  For iLine = LBound(strAcro, 2) To UBound(strAcro, 2)
    If strAcro(0, iLine) = strArg Then Exit For
  Next

  Select Case strCom
    Case "\acs":
      Selection.InsertBefore (strAcro(0, iLine))
    Case "\acsp":
      Selection.InsertBefore (strAcro(0, iLine)) & "s"
    Case "\acl":
      Selection.InsertBefore (strAcro(1, iLine))
    Case "\aclp":
      Selection.InsertBefore (strAcro(1, iLine)) & "s"
    Case "\acf":
      Selection.InsertBefore (strAcro(1, iLine)) & " (" & (strAcro(0, iLine)) & ")"
    Case "\acfp":
      Selection.InsertBefore (strAcro(1, iLine)) & "s (" & (strAcro(0, iLine)) & "s)"
    Case "\ac":
      If strAcro(2, iLine) = True Then
        Selection.InsertBefore (strAcro(0, iLine))
      Else
        Selection.InsertBefore (strAcro(1, iLine))
        strAcro(2, iLine) = True
      End If
      Case "\acp":
      If strAcro(2, iLine) = True Then
        Selection.InsertBefore (strAcro(0, iLine)) & "s"
      Else
        Selection.InsertBefore (strAcro(1, iLine)) & "s"
        strAcro(2, iLine) = True
      End If
    End Select
  Case "\acresetall":
    For iLine = LBound(strAcro, 2) To UBound(strAcro, 2)
      strAcro(2, iLine) = "False"
    Next
Case Else
  Stop
  Debug.Print strCom
  'just put strArg back
  If Selection = "{" Then
    Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strArg) + 2, Extend:=True
    Selection.Delete
  End If
  Selection.InsertBefore (strArg)
End Select
```

End If
End If
If Selection.Text = "$" Then
  bInMath = Not (bInMath)
  Selection.Delete
  Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
End If

If Selection.Text = "^" Then  'superscript
  Selection.Delete
  strArg = CaptureBraces
  doSuper (strArg)
End If
'If Selection.Text = "*" Then Stop
If Selection.Text = "*" And bInMath Then 'superscript (in math mode)
  Selection.Delete
  strArg = CaptureBraces
  doSub (strArg)
End If

Loop 'walking doc

'finish
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = False

ActiveDocument.Save
End Sub

Function FindGreek(searchstring As String) As Integer
Dim greek(1 To 24) As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim match As Integer
greek(1) = "alpha"
greek(2) = "beta"
greek(3) = "gamma"
greek(4) = "delta"
greek(5) = "epsilon"
greek(6) = "zeta"
greek(7) = "eta"
greek(8) = "theta"
greek(9) = "iota"
greek(10) = "kappa"
greek(11) = "lambda"
greek(12) = "mu"
greek(13) = "nu"
greek(14) = "xi"
greek(15) = "omicron"
greek(16) = "pi"
greek(17) = "rho"
greek(18) = "sigma"
greek(19) = "tau"
greek(20) = "upsilon"
greek(21) = "phi"
greek(22) = "chi"
greek(23) = "psi"
greek(24) = "omega"
For x = LBound(greek) To UBound(greek)
    If greek(x) = searchstring Then
        match = x
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
FindGreek = match
End Function

Sub doSuper(strX As String)
If Selection.Text = "{" Then Selection.Delete
If Len(strX) >= 1 Then 'bracketed expression
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strX), Extend:=True
  Selection.Font.Superscript = True
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  Selection.Delete
Else 'single char
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=True
  Selection.Font.Superscript = True
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
End If
Selection.Font.Superscript = False
Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
End Sub
Sub doSub(strX As String)
If Selection.Text = "{" Then Selection.Delete
If Len(strX) >= 1 Then 'bracketed expression
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(strX), Extend:=True
  Selection.Font.Subscript = True
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  Selection.Delete
Else 'single char
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=True
  Selection.Font.Subscript = True
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
End If
Selection.Font.Subscript = False
Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
End Sub

Function CaptureBraces()
Dim strRet As String
Dim iBraceCount As Integer
iBraceCount = 0
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="CJH_cap_brace"
If Selection.Text = " " Then Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
If Selection.Text = "" Then Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=1
If Selection.Text <> "{" Then
  strRet = ""
  Exit Function
End If
'iBraceCount = 1
Do
  Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=1
  Select Case Right(Selection.Text, 1)
    Case "{": iBraceCount = iBraceCount + 1
    Case "}": iBraceCount = iBraceCount - 1
    Case Else
  End Select
Loop Until iBraceCount = 0
strRet = Mid(Selection.Text, 2, Len(Selection.Text) - 2)

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("CJH_cap_brace").Select
CaptureBraces = strRet
End Function

Sub setOptions()
With Options
  .PasteAdjustWordSpacing = False
End With
End Sub

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this vba code, it is what I am planning to do right now. But your code will save me much time. I wonder if you can give me the .dot file and a template .tex via email. If yes, I would be very appreciated. My email address is ming.su@live.com. thank you in advance

Comment: Rather than email, I'll put it up for everyone on google docs.  But as you can see, it's not (very well) commented, and I don't have a lot of time to spend on it at the moment. [template](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwgkzFOxrfe9eVhrdXFEeVJ6UjQ/edit?usp=sharing) [sample .tex](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwgkzFOxrfe9bGFfWTBGdWFMdG8/edit?usp=sharing).  I've set it up so anyone can comment, but not edit.  Please share anything you add by commenting (not tested) - if anything major, I'll try to merge it in.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been using your .dot file and adapt it to my tex file, the idea is great, but my tex file has to many functions. So i added many thing in your code.