# Equations as pictures in text

Tags: pdftex, tikz-external, preview

Is there a way to compile a document with pdflatex and render all displaymath into graphics which are then included in the document instead of the equation code itself?

Analogous to what you can do with tikz graphics and the externalize library?

Comment: Just to know: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I write in tex but my supervisor loves word. I do not want to mess with tex4ht right now so I thought if I could render the math in pictures the equations won't get screwed up when I convert from pdf to docx (and they do get messed up right now)

Comment: Exporting `pdf` as `png` isn't good enough?

Comment: Converting to Word from a .pdf is much worse than tex4ht or similar tools --- all semantic markup is lost, one gets new paragraphs at the end of every page, &c.

Comment: @WillAdams I do not care much about that to be honest. It is just for the proofreader to add comments. The final document going to print is a pdf from pdflatex. 
My reasons aside, I think the question is still worth asking

Comment: Why can't the proofreader just add editing comments to the (LaTeX-generated) PDF directly?  That's the way we do it around here.

Comment: Not only that, it's much easier now to have it done since one no longer must encrypt the .pdf or especially enable it for such annotation: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70050/my-phd-supervisor-wants-me-to-use-word-because-they-cant-edit-latex-what-to-do/123753#123753