# Is there an alternative way to double quote in Latex?

Tags: punctuation

I am editing my Latex code using MS Word. Before you get any ideas (I know it's weird) please refer [How to run Latex from Word?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61967/how-to-run-latex-from-word)

Having found myself in this unusual predicament, I also have to use double quotes quite often. So what is `’’` becomes `’’` which is correct, but what I really want is `''`. To make it clear, I am trying to end the double quotes with the aforementioned two characters, but word modifies the standard apostrophe.

So is there a different way to double quote a "phrase" in Latex? I was looking for something similar to `\dbquote{phrase}`.

P.S.: Needless to add, the modification that MS Word does on `''` results in an incorrect output. For example, `"phrase"` is rendered with just the initial double quotes like `"phrase`.

Comment: Take a look a the ``csquotes`` package. That should provide exactly what you want.

Comment: On a side note: Can't you configure the [AutoCorrect](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-HA010173242.aspx#BM13) options in a way that typing `"phrase"` becomes `“phrase”`?

Comment: @BenediktBauer Thanks! @ Qrrb No how the quotes appear is not the issue, is just that the ending quotes don't appear at all, is my issue.

Comment: @ShashankSawant Nonetheless, I'd turn those nasty AutoCorrect things off. But that's just me.

Comment: @ShashankSawant it is _not that crazy_ to edit LaTeX documents in Word. I do it sometimes too, but my reason might be different: I have to convert Word articles of other people into LaTeX, and adding LaTeX markup directly into the document is then the easiest way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LaTeX provides:

- `\textquotedblleft` for `“`,
- `\textquotedblright` for `”`,
- `\textquoteleft` for `‘` and
- `\textquoteright` for `’`.

You can define your own macro:

```
\newcommand\dblquote[1]{\textquotedblleft #1\textquotedblright}
\newcommand\sglquote[1]{\textquoteleft #1\textquoteright}
```

Or you use the [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package that provides nested language sensitive quote enclosing:

```
\enquote{Phrase\enquote{inner quote}}
```

For single quotes:

```
\enquote*{Phrase}
```

Comment: Trying it right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off the auto-correct of quotes, and then you can use the key *on the left from key 1* for the starting quotes, and the key *on the right from key L* for the ending quote.

Another option is to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, which should correctly display the quotes if the appropriate fonts are loaded (surely `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` should be enough, I'm even not sure if it's necessary).