# Making corrections during review of other people latex article

Tags: highlighting, collaboration, changes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Track changes” in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65453/track-changes-in-latex)

There is the corrections mode in Word package. All your changes will be marked. In this way one can show proposed changes in other people documents.

What is analog in Tex?

Comment: see also `latexdiff originalfile.tex newfile.tex`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a number of packages that you could use: [`todonotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) and [`changebar`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changebar) are two of them; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{changebar}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{changebar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{changebar}
\lipsum*[2] text text
\todo[prepend]{A very long and tedious
note that cannot be on one line in the list of todos.}.
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For some external tools, you could see ["Track changes" in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65453/3954)