# How to draw a big red cross through large parts of a text?

Tags: packages

I am co-authoring a piece of text, and I would like to indicate that in my opinion certain parts should be removed, by drawing a big red cross through that specific section. I have tried to work with tikz, but this usually ends up in procrastinating by exploring the awesomeness of Tikz.

What I need is being able to just add a line before and after the section needed to be discussed, such as:

```
\begin{cross}
    This text should be removed or discussed
\end{cross}
```

Is there a package that enables this?

Comment: Have you seen `changes` package? A simple example is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65453/track-changes-in-latex/65466#65466

Comment: For American readers... the request means to draw a big red **X** through the specified text.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here is a solution which allows page breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{cross}{blank,breakable,parbox=false,
  overlay={\draw[red,line width=5pt] (interior.south west)--(interior.north east);
    \draw[red,line width=5pt] (interior.north west)--(interior.south east);}}

\begin{document}

\begin{cross}
\lipsum[1]
\end{cross}

\par\bigskip
Now a part that continues to the next page:
\par\bigskip

\begin{cross}
\lipsum[2-9]
\end{cross}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I am once more amazed by the possibilities of your nice package!

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for the flowers :-)

Answer (score 12):

This will work only in a page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\coordinate (#1) {};}
\newenvironment{cross}{%
\noindent\tikzmark{lbegin}\hfill \tikzmark{rbegin}
}{%
\par\noindent\tikzmark{lend}\hfill \tikzmark{rend}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[red,thick] (lbegin) -- (rend);
    \draw[red,thick] (rbegin) -- (lend);    
\end{tikzpicture}\par
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%
\begin{cross}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{cross}

%
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Check out the changes package. Simply crossing out the text you want removed might be too little functionality. What if you have comments on why to remove certain text passages?

[An example of how to use this package](http://www.poeschko.com/2012/01/highlighting-changes-in-latex/)

Comment: `changes` is great but, by default, it has problems with multi-paragraph text and equations. In principle it can be configured to use this solution if it can detect it is needed. For example, to make `changes` work on math mode, I have this code in my preamble `\newcommand{\stkout}[1]{\ifmmode\cancel{#1}\else\sout{#1}\fi}`.

Answer (score 5):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node,lipsum}

\newsavebox\IBox
\newenvironment{criscross}{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\IBox}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \parindent=\xxx\relax
    \ignorespaces
}{%
    \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \noindent
    \psDefBoxNodes{N}{\usebox\IBox}%
    \psline[linecolor=red](N:tl)(N:br)%
    \psline[linecolor=red](N:bl)(N:tr)%
    \ignorespacesafterend
}

\AtBeginDocument{\newlength\xxx\xxx=\parindent}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{Don't be lukewarm! If you cannot be the best, be the worst!}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{criscross}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{criscross}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One  down vote detected... Oh my ghost!

Answer (score 4):

A big red cross might be a bit awkward-looking.  Through a squarish paragraph it would look OK (as in Harish Kumar's answer, but what if the block spans a page break?  Or is only 1 long line?

The [`ulem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package provides `\sout{}` like strikethrough and `\xout{}` where a slash is overlaid on each character.  Coloured versions can easily be created, according to the manual.