# Strike out over graphics

Tags: graphics, strikeout

I have a document with a graphics and I want to replaced this graphics with another as part of a revision. To make this clear I want to show the old version of a figure next (or below) to the new version, but struck out.

I tried using the `changes` package (`\deleted` around the `\includegraphics` command) which gives an error and also with the `sout` package, which gives a weird result.

**How can strike out a graphics reliable in LaTeX?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics{old} \\ %strike this figure out, with a diagonal, horizontal or cross lines
   \includegraphics{new}
   \caption{description}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the selected answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135331/how-to-draw-a-big-red-cross-through-large-parts-of-a-text) to get what you've asked:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{cross}{blank,breakable,parbox=false,
  overlay={\draw[red,line width=5pt] (interior.south west)--(interior.north east);
    \draw[red,line width=5pt] (interior.north west)--(interior.south east);}}
\begin{document}
\begin{cross}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{P1.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{cross}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{P2.pdf}
\end{center}
\caption{Use the correct diagram!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output in Gummi looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. 1) this deserves to be somehow used by one of the strike out packages. 2) `changes` could fall back to this when other types of strike out don't work (see comment in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135334/1871)

Comment: When I copy and paste this code, adjust the image file names, and run it, the cross appears *behind* the image -- what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This worked, though (you may have to adjust the location of the corners to the size of your image, or vice versa):


`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(mypic){\includegraphics[width=2in]{image}};
\node[above left of = mypic](corner1){};
\node[above right of = mypic](corner2){};
\node[below left of = mypic](corner3){};
\node[below right of = mypic](corner4){};
\draw[red, thick](corner1)--(corner4);
\draw[red, thick](corner2)--(corner3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Yes, the cross appears behind the image. I don't know how to get in on top of the image, but the approach does avoid the hassle of adjusting the location of the corners.

Comment: Thanks to @NCH32 , I got to find a way to locate the cross in front of the image as well as automatically fit the cross to the size of your image! https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/487546/185010

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, adapted from an answer [over here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {
            \includegraphics{my_figure.png}
        };
        \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
            \draw[red,line width=1 mm] (0, 1)--(1, 0);
            \draw[red,line width=1 mm] (0, 0)--(1, 1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```