# Crossed out red box fitting tightly around image

Tags: graphics, boxes

I can do

```
\textcolor{red}{
  \fbox{
    \includegraphics{path}
  }
}
```

To get a red frame sitting tightly around an image inside a `firgure` environment. Now, is there a way to also get a red cross over the image?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A TikZ solution that includes the image file inside a `tikzpicture` and draws a square and cross relative to the coordinates of the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \draw[red,ultra thick] (image.south east) -- (image.north west);
    \draw[red,ultra thick] (image.north east) -- (image.south west);
    \draw[red,ultra thick] (image.south west) rectangle (image.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My compliments for your answer. I have deleted my previous comment for the OP.

Comment: Even shorter: `\draw[red,ultra thick] (image.south west) rectangle (image.north east); \draw[red,ultra thick] (image.south east) -- (image.north west); \draw[red,ultra thick] (image.north east) -- (image.south west);` ;-)

Comment: @AndiW Better indeed :) I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. When changing the answer, you forgot one of the diagonals in the cross. You might want to fix that. Personally I also liked it better without `ultra thick` (then it's also more similar to `\fbox`) but I guess that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 6):

as supplement to @Marjin answer (+1), a little bit shorter code ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node  (image) [inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}};
\draw[red,ultra thick]  (image.south west) -- (image.north east)
                        (image.north west) -- (image.south east)
                        (image.south west) rectangle (image.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

the result is similar:

[image]