# How can I temporarily change text colour?

Tags: color

I'm making corrections to a report and the examiner would like my amendments highlighted in red. Of course, if(!) they are accepted, I would then have to produce an unmarked (black text) pdf.

Rather than put `\color{red}` before each section of text I would like to highlight, and then remove each instance later, is there a way I can put a marker before such text (e.g. `\tempcolour`) that can then be controlled in the document header? (e.g. `tempcolour = red/black`)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We appreciate a working document, at the moment this question is a little bit unclear. A `\color{...}` is durable until another change will occur. It's better to wrap in a group or a command

Comment: Hi Christian - sorry I was just trying to be brief! I would've wrapped in all the affected text yes.

Comment: That's what I've done and you can switch off here and there, where appropiate, using `\proofreadtrue` or `\proofreadfalse` (or remove the `\changemarker` wrapper finally for the approved portions

Comment: While not a true duplicate, this sounds a lot like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65453/10038

Comment: @Shep: Welcome from me, too, and a warm advice: take care to add an MWE. Even if you think it's unnecessary cos you only need a very short input or hint to go on and there are plenty of non-MWE advice around. From experience, if you don't and instead point out to these two points, all hell might break loose and you may well be exaggeratively defamed and boycotted. Please spare that yourself.

Comment: @Lucas: Please come down ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something like this?

Define a `conditional` named, say `\ifproofread` and set to true for those parts that are not yet confirmed/accepted. If the proof read mode is false, the `\changemarker` expands to the usual (black) text.

Another way is to use `\color{red} some text \normalcolor` but this requires the resetting every time after the text. (Ah, just seen, Herbert does use this approach in his answer!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\newif\ifproofread




\newcommand{\changemarker}[1]{%
\ifproofread
\textcolor{red}{#1}%
\else
#1%
\fi
}

\begin{document}
\proofreadfalse  % All is accepted so far

Here is something. \changemarker{And this is added by me}

\proofreadtrue  % From now one, this is not yet confirmed. 


Here is something. \changemarker{And this is added by me and was not yet accepted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is interesting!

Answer (score 16):

You can define `\change` and `\stopchange` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\change}{%
  \@bsphack
  \leavevmode
  \color{red}%
  \@esphack
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\stopchange}{%
  \@bsphack
  \normalcolor
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some words \change \lipsum*[2] \stopchange and again normal color

Some words \lipsum*[2] and again normal color

\change Also at start of paragraphs and going across line breaks
without any particular problem \stopchange with color returning normal.

Also at start of paragraphs and going across line breaks
without any particular problem with color returning normal.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but after `\stopchange`, all the `tikz` graphics still use red color.  Would it be possible to adapt the solution so it works also in this case?  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 15):

What about the [changes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/changes) package?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, columnsep=1cm, 
paperwidth=14cm, paperheight=10cm]{geometry} % just for the MWE layout
\usepackage[xcolor={divpdf,grey},authormarkup=none]{changes} 
\definechangesauthor[name={Exempli Gratia},color=orange]{EG}
\definechangesauthor[name={Dean Cavalier},color=green!50!black]{DC}
\definechangesauthor[name={Fran Meanbash}, color=red]{FM}
\begin{document}
\replaced[id=EG]{You are}{He is} so inefficient%
\deleted[id=FM,remark={Be polite, please.}]{ and idiot} 
that you will be fired \added[id=DC]{ soon}. 
\replaced{Have a nice day!}{ That's all.}
\newpage\footnotesize
\listofchanges[style=summary]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

To hide all the changes if they are accepted, simply add the `final` option to the package,
i.e., `\usepackage[final, ....]{changes}` and you will have this:

[image: mwe2]

Note that in the `draft` version  (default) you can also turn out globally the markup of deleted/added changes with `addedmarkup=none`, `deletedmarkup=none` and turn black individual changes providing a `id` of a fake author associated with color black:

```
\definechangesauthor[name={Accepted}, color=black]{A}
...
\added[id=A]{accepted addition}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{xspace}
 \newcommand\mycolor{\color{red}\xspace}
 ...
 foo \mycolor bar \normalcolor baz
```

later you can change the macro `\mycolor` to use `black` instead of `red`. You can also define `\mycolor`  with an argument:

```
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \newcommand\mycolor[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
 ...
 foo \mycolor{bar} baz
```

Answer (score 4):

If the intention is to help tracking changes rather than highlighting parts of the text, keeping the LaTeX source under a version control system (git, mercurial, subversion,...) and using the `latexdiff` script (included in the main distributions, or available from [this git repository](https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff.git)) to generate a source file with changes highlighted.

This is (for this kind of workflow) easy to use, as one does not actually ever interfere with the markup of the document, hence no need to take back annotations added for a previous round. Instead, it automatically provides a LaTeX source where all the changes are highlighted (with your choice of many possible styles).

Comment: This is true, but not really what the asker is looking for. The person the asker is working with may require red text in the output rather than looking at source files.

Comment: @Null but this is exactly what latexdiff results in when the output is compiled, e.g. into a PDF, s. last pages at http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/doc/latexdiff-man.pdf . Or am I missing something there?