# Translations from other languages for English with Latex

Tags: macros, languages, translator, translate

1. The problem with doing translations in LaTeX is this: I use the [Wordfast](https://www.wordfast.net/) program to "record' everything that I tranlsate (Worfast is not a machine translation tool; it is a macro that runs inside Word and records in a .txt file every sentence in Portuguese and every sentence in English that I translate manually). Wordfast is designed to operate with the Word and as far as I am aware it doesn't work with LaTeX mark-up language.
2. As for editing texts in English written in LaTeX, the big advantage
   of Word is that I can use the Track Changes facility to see the
   changes I make and the original text. Does LaTeX offer a similar
   editing facility?

Comment: Latex is not even a "program", at least not as Word is, but rather it's a mark-up language based on the program called TeX. I don't think an application like Wordfast would work with it, because the methodology is drastically different. Not to mention that "Wordfast" seems to be named specifically to be used with Word.

Comment: Hello @Alenanno, thank​ you so much for your remarks, I edited the question text.

Comment: There are already questions on tracking changes (e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65453/7883).  While it’s not especially related to TeX, you may be interested in OmegaT (http://www.omegat.org/), a cross-platform program for translators whose output is, I think, easier to turn into a `.tex` file when the time comes to typeset your translation.

Comment: Hello @Thérèse, I liked your suggestion and I will study the OmegaT!  Thank​ you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Is there any news here?