# Facing problem with "Trackchanges" package

Tags: trackchanges

I am revising my manuscript according to suggestions made by editor including some grammatical corrections, and the editor wants me to display all the editing that I will make. For this purpose, I find Track changes package very useful. Although this package is running well with every of template available with me but when I load this package in the Svjour3 template I am getting following error:

LaTeX Error: Command \note already defined.

Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for the explanation.
Type H  for immediate help.
 ...

l.662 }

Your command was ignored.
Type I   to replace it with another command,
or  to continue without it.

Although I can avoid this error message by typing 'R' in error console but I want to know what this error is all about and why this package is running with other templates.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

- Apparently, the `Svjour3` document class defines a command that is called `\note`. (I did not find it in my MiKTeX installation, by the way)
- The `trackchanges` package also defines a command that has the name `\note`.
- **You could try a different package, e. g.`\usepackage[]{changes}`.**
- The documentation of the `changes` package can be found [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/changes).
- Typical commands are `\added[]{text}` (or `\deleted` or `\replaced`).
- I have searched the documentation -- I did not found a command called `\note` :).
- See ["Track changes" in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65453) for more information about showing changes in LaTeX documents (including the `changes` package).

Comment: When I remove the note command from `trackchanges.sty` everything start working fine.

Comment: @IgoiiT Good, apparently there are no side effects in this case. But changing the style file is not a proper way to solve a LaTeX problem in general. But in this case, I think that it is ok.

Comment: @IgotiT No. You shouldn't change the style file. You should make a copy with a new name and modify that. You should never change a distributed file without renaming it. (OK. There are some very exceptional cases where you might do this if you are very, very careful. But you then have to be very, very careful and should only do it for the briefest possible temporary period.)